# Issue with query greatest n per group with distinct

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a query shown below that I would like to be able to use to show a list of the most recent change to a user. The table the records are housed in can contain multiple changes per student sometimes, but I would only like to show the most recent one per user.

For some reason, when using MAX(timestamp) it is only returning ONE user entry, and not the other users. If I remove the MAX(timestamp) It goes back to returning all records, not just one. If I add the MAX onto the timestamp back it sometimes shows only a single user change, sometimes none... Any help would be appreciated

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT 
            rID
            , r.studentID
            , oldMethod
            ,newMethod
            ,oldSubMethod
            ,newSubMethod
            ,timestamp
            ,r.staffID
            ,type
            , o.methodName oldName
            , n.methodName newName
            , s.firstName fName
            , s.lastName lName 
         FROM changeReport r
         LEFT 
         JOIN methodLookup o
           ON o.methodID = r.oldMethod
         LEFT 
         JOIN methodLookup n
           ON n.methodID = r.newMethod
         JOIN s s
           ON s.studentID = r.studentID
         LEFT 
         JOIN staffaccounts a
           ON r.staffID = a.staffID
        WHERE '$bnu' IN (newSubMethod,oldSubMethod) 
          AND DATE(timestamp) = CURRENT_DATE
     ) a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT s.studentID
            , MAX(timestamp) timestamp
         FROM changeReport r
         LEFT 
         JOIN methodLookup o
           ON o.methodID = r.oldMethod
         LEFT 
         JOIN methodLookup n
           ON n.methodID = r.newMethod
         JOIN s s
           ON s.studentID = r.studentID
         LEFT 
         JOIN staffaccounts a
           ON r.staffID = a.staffID
        WHERE '$bnu' IN (newSubMethod,oldSubMethod) 
          AND DATE(timestamp) = CURRENT_DATE
    ) b
   ON b.studentID = a.studentID
  AND b.timestamp = a.timestamp
```

Comment: You're missing the appropriate GROUP BY in the `b` subquery. _As an aside, your query should run faster if you rework the `DATE(timestamp) = CURRENT_DATE` into something like `timetamp BETWEEN startOfCurrentDate AND endOfCurrentDate`; using functions, like DATE(), on field values in conditions tends to hurt performance significantly._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MAX`, `COUNT`, `MIN`, `AVG`, etc are all grouping methods in MySQL.

As such, and as a simple example, if you just

```
SELECT username, MAX(date)
FROM table
```

you'll end up with only one result which is the one with the most recent timestamp.

If you want to get every username with its latest update you should do:

```
SELECT username, MAX(date)
FROM table
GROUP BY username
```

In that way, you're being explicit about you wanting to group the query output and how do you want to group it

Comment: Actually, there is no guarantee they would end up with the one with the most recent timestamp; it is more likely they would receive the first username inserted into the table and the most recent timestamp, which could be completely unrelated to each other.

Comment: yes, you're indeed correct... either way, it's not what the OP is expecting to get :)

Comment: How would I go about doing it properly then?

Comment: Actually, Somehow it seems to be working perfectly as i spot  check.. one of the fields seems to be off a little, but it is one we don't use. All the important information seems to be going properly. Any ideas on how it should be improved?

Comment: in the `b` subquery, you should add `GROUP BY s.student_id` after the last `AND` clause